# Mongodb c# driver version 2.2.3.3

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

I am unable to find documentation for latest version (2.2.3.3)of c# driver for mongodb. There is no update on git as well about the latest version. Please help me figure out the documentation for newest c# driver.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like we didn't update the documentation here: http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-csharp-driver/. 2.2.0 will have exactly the same documentation as 2.2.3 cause a patch release doesn't make any API changes. My apologies for not having that updated. We'll get that updated asap.